# How do you use HTTP2 lib with EXPRESS js?, i get this problem TypeError: Cannot read property 'readable' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, http2

```
const http2 = require('http2'); const fs = require('fs'); const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('*', (req, res) => { res.status(200).end('ok'); });

const server = http2.createSecureServer({ key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'), cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt'), }, app);

server.listen(20020);
```

Comment: The express framework don't supports the native nodejs http2 module. Now you can use the [express-h2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-h2) module. [Read more here](https://medium.com/@kissema1/the-easy-way-to-use-http2-protocol-with-express-framework-dfae4f8e9689?source=friends_link&sk=b6986b8dac15016b684b08b618567249)

Answer (score 1):

1) **http2** not supported by **express**, use **https** instead ([link to issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3388)):

```
const https = require('https'); 
const fs = require('fs'); 
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('*', (req, res) => { res.status(200).end('ok'); });

const server = https.createServer({ 
  key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'), 
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt'), 
}, app);

server.listen(20020);
```

2) instead of using server resources for encryption better use http and let **nginx** to serve as **https**, **http2** connection server.

Comment: How is it possible that Express still doesn't support HTTP2 in 2020?

Comment: it's incorrect to use https and/or http2 in nodejs, except in 1 possible situation when You've microservices and they are located in different datacenters and communication not secured by some secured tunnel. but kubernetes networking layer also can provide that tunnel so still http is enough.

Comment: why is it incorrect to use https or http2 in node.js?

Comment: @Liga encryption is cpu intensive task for nodejs. nginx does this better. if You want to check use apache benchmark and see difference.

Comment: Node's `https` and `http2` modules depend on `node:crypto` which uses OpenSSL under the hood, it's just a wrapper around OpenSSL. So, the computationally-intensive encryption tasks are done by OpenSSL.

Comment: @AradAlvand what You've wrote is nice. But my answer is 3 years old which I may say a bit outdated to judge using current changes in express and nodejs. In case of making backend app I don't recommend to serve https, http2 connection termination using app. Cause every part of system architecture must do it's own job. Like nginx or litehttp or whatever for http(s)(2), quic and etc protocols. App level job is to do business logic. Unless that app is something special - like http firewall infront of nginx to analyze traffic and mitigate ddos.

Comment: @AradAlvand continuing the talk about reason to not handle http2, https connections on app level is that Your app is "naked" against clients and so all hard work will do Your app and other business parts of app may suffer with inefficient cpu, memory usage.
Think about You wrote nodejs api and handle https, http2 without nginx at front. Anyone can send You big payload and make Your api to parse request - even if You set body size limit in body parser - it will parse body in any case unless the limit.
+ in case of 1000s static file requests backend api will be doing cyphering which 50% cpu

Comment: @num8e Sure, I'm not disputing the utility and in some cases the necessity of reverse proxies. However, there are scenarios where you do actually have reverse proxies in front of your app (e.g. CDN edge servers), but still want HTTPS connections between those proxy servers and your (Node.js) application, if for example the communication is done via an unteusted channel (i.e. the public internet). I was just pointing out that in these cases it'd be pretty reasonable to use Node's `https` module, and performance wouldn't be a concern, since it's all just OpenSSL under the hood.

Comment: @AradAlvand Yes, as client usage http(2|s) are inevitable, I use https module for client connection when I don't want to use axios and etc external modules to have more control on buffers and etc.